# Strange polish chars and gettext

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I'm trying to localize my page with gettext. Here is my code:

```
$locale = "pl_PL";
if (isSet($_GET["lang"])) $locale = $_GET["lang"];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
textdomain("messages");
```

When I call

```
echo _("hello");
```

the output text is

```
"cze's'c" //instead of "cześć"
```

To translate po files and generate mo files I'm using PoEdit. Charset is everywhere UTF8. What could be wrong?

Comment: have you set charset in your .po file? `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"` also look at `bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8'); solved problem! Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer you can mark it and in that way question will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Set it to your .po files.

Moreover, take a look at `bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');`